# Icon for .desktop file not showing

Tags: release-freya, icons, app-shortcuts

I created a .desktop file to launch Chrome in a specific profile. Here is the code:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Chrome School
Comment=Open Chrome in my school account
Exec=google-chrome --profile-directory="Profile 1"
Icon=/home/coolo/Pictures/ChromeGold
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Internet;Application;
```

It works after making it executable, but the icon won't show.
[image: Icon Missing] 
How do I fix this and make the icon show?

Comment: Doesn't the icon have any extension?

Comment: @shrestha_aj It does, but a guide on the Ubuntu wiki said something about not including the file extension.

Comment: Also, I think I have the wrong category names. Can someone tell me the right ones?

Comment: Try `Categories=Network;WebBrowser;` and put the extension for the icon image as show by @Ryan below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try including the file extension in the icon name. For example, if it's a PNG file, change the code to `Icon=/home/coolo/Pictures/ChromeGold.png`.

Comment: Then why does [this Ubuntu Wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles) says not to include the file extension for the image?

Comment: Elementary uses Slingshot, while Ubuntu uses the Unity Launcher. Seems like the two launchers have slightly different expectations for what `.desktop` files should look contain.

Comment: Oh. That makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem with SqlWorkbenchJ. I fixed it putting the .png image set in sqlworkbench.desktop under "Icon" into the directory /usr/share/pixmaps.

After that, the application started to show the proper icon either in plank dock and applications menu.

Hope it helps.